# confused on how scope and constructors work in angular

Tags: angularjs

I was following a tutorial on meteor and angular and am using the controller as defined below. However, this seems to be different then the typical declaration and am confused how this one is different. Specifically I would like to change `$scope.phone` in `addNumber` but I can not figure out how to do it. It is being passed into the function via `ng-model`. I am wondering what the `constructor($scope)` is doing. Thanks.

```
class TodosListCtrl {
  constructor($scope) {
    $scope.viewModel(this);
    $scope.phone = '';
    $scope.first = '';
    $scope.last = '';
  }
  addNumber(first,last,phone){
    Numbers.insert({
      first_name: first,
      last_name: last,
      number: phone,
      createdAt: new Date
  });
  // tried
  // phone = ''; 
  //this.phone = '';
  //$scope.phone didnt work
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, add this line:

```
  constructor($scope) {
    'ngInject';  // add this to ensure injection occurs.
    $scope.viewModel(this);
    $scope.phone = '';
    $scope.first = '';
    $scope.last = '';

    this.$scope = $scope;
  }
```

And then in your `addNumber`:

```
  addNumber(first,last,phone) {
    Numbers.insert({
      first_name: first,
      last_name: last,
      number: phone,
      createdAt: new Date
    });
    this.$scope.phone = phone;
  }
```

Since the `addNumber` function runs later than the constructor, you need to store a reference to the `$scope` somehow. The easiest way to do this is by adding it to `this`.

Comment: Awesome thanks. also any idea on what the point of the constructor($scope) is or is in the implementation of the controller class?

Comment: `$scope` is injected into the class by the angular framework using its dependency injection engine.  Usually, there is a `ngInject` in the constructor to signal to the framework that the class is injectable. I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering what the constructor($scope) is doing. Thanks.

This is injecting a dependency into the constructor. That's all. It doesn't give you access to the injected `$scope` instance anywhere else in the controller unless you assign the instance given in the controller to your controller's `this` instance. You could do that (as Andrew Eisenberg suggested), however, if you're using this controller in conjunction with a directive (which you probably should be, stand alone controllers are very rare in modern angular practices), then it's much easier to set `bindToController: true` on the directive definition, which will automatically append all properties on your controller `this` instance to the local scope.

If you use components instead (which I would recommend for anything that results in DOM creation), then this setting is automatically applied. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component for reference.